# Не создается задача в планировщике для текущего пользователя в Windows-домене

Tags: c#, long-poll

Задача: сделать автозагрузку программы с админскими правами (установлена в Program Files). Программа использует Long Polling для установления длительного соединения с сервером, и по этому соединению получает команды (открыть окно в браузере при наступлении события).

Есть код, который **должен** создавать задания в планировщике заданий для каждого пользователя (или группы пользователей).

файл: \WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Installer1.cs

```
using (var computerEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path))
{
    var userNames = from DirectoryEntry childEntry in computerEntry.Children
                    where childEntry.SchemaClassName == "User"
                    select childEntry.Name;
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var name in userNames)
    {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            try
            {
                string taskname = "MyProgramRun" + i.ToString();
                TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
                td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "RUN MyProgram Every Logon";
                td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger { Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) });
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(Context.Parameters["path"], null, null));
                td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskname, td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, name, null, TaskLogonType.None);
            }
            catch { }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Данный код на обычном домашнем компе создает четыре задания в планировщике (по одному для каждого юзера); и во время загрузки системы срабатывает одно из правил, в зависимости от того под кем грузимся.

Однако на компьютере **внутри организации, где компьютеры работают не в группе (например WORRKGROUP), а в локальном домене, задания для текущего юзера (который устанавливает программу) - не создается!**

Вот задания, которые создает данный код, запускаемый на компьютере в локальном домене, из-под пользователя локального домена:

```
MyProgramRun0 - DefaultAccout (PC-NAME)  
MyProgramRun1 - localusr (PC-NAME)  
MyProgramRun2 - Администратор (PC-NAME)  
MyProgramRun3 - Гость (PC-NAME)
```

Но задачи для нашего текущего юзера, под которым работает пользователь; под которым он устанавливает программу; и под которым эта программа должна грузиться - не создается.

При этом, юзер в группе Администраторы.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/WFEorhX.png]

**Как написать код, который будет создавать задания для пользователей домена, а не только для локальных пользователей?**

Пользователь домена выглядит как: COMPANYNAME\user.name

Если положить исполняемый файл в реестр:
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

то программа просто не запускается, так как из реестра автозапуска с админскими правами сделать как я понял нельзя.

Варианта видится два:

1). Переписать программу с Long Polling таким образом, чтобы она не требовала админских прав (не уверен что это возможно)

2). Заставить программу создавать задачи в планировщике в том числе для пользователей домена

Кусок кода где создается соединение:
\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\LongPoll.cs

```
public void Poling() {
    string url = IPs.Default.IPServer + IPs.Default.IPpoll;//Адресс сервера,  куда отправляем запросы
    string Respurl;
    while (poll) {
        try {
            if (UserName != null && Password != null) {
                string postString = String.Format("LoginForm[manager]={0}&LoginForm[password]={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(UserName), Uri.EscapeDataString(Password));
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);//создаем запрос к нашему серверу
                request.Method = "POST";
                StreamWriter requestWrite = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());//создаем поток для записи запроса
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                requestWrite.Write(postString);
                requestWrite.Close();
                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();//отправляем запрос, получаем ответ
                Stream dataStream = resp.GetResponseStream(); //поток для записи ответа
                XmlDocument XdocTime = new XmlDocument();
                XdocTime.Load(dataStream);//загружаем хмл док
                XmlNode xNode = XdocTime.DocumentElement;
                Respurl = xNode.FirstChild.InnerText;
                Process.Start(IPs.Default.IPServer + Respurl);
            } else { }
        } catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: ОС: Windows 10 корпоративная